# Why does std::list have remove and remove_if functions

Tags: c++, algorithm

Why does std::list have remove and remove_if functions? That seems to duplicate behavior with the algorithm functions of the same name. If remove and remove_if make sense, why not find and find_if?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, they have different semantics. `std::list::remove_if` erases the removed elements, and `std::remove_if` doesn't. `std::remove_if` also requires the container elements to be MoveAssignable, while `std::list::remove_if` only requires them to be Erasable.

There is actually no *complexity* differences between both (they both are O(n)), but `std::remove_if` could be about two times slower because of the need to do list traversal using two independent pointers instead of just one - and list traversal on most modern CPUs is a quite expensive operation. If the move operation for the container element type is expensive, this can additionally slow down `std::remove_if`.

Answer (score 4):

That's because given the nature of `std::list` (or more precisely - the likely implementation forced by the standard), standard algorithms like `std::remove` and `std::remove_if` are inefficient when used on it.

`std::list`'s implementation has to meet some requirements, which essentially force it to be node-based, linked with pointers structure.

This very implementation has its cons. For example, it does not allow for random-access iterators, thus `std::sort` will simply not work for it, since it *requires* random-access. This is the extreme case. There are efficient algorithms which do work with the specific nature of `std::list` likely implementation and they are used in the member `std::list::sort`. While `std::sort` *could* use the same implementation, other scenarious would likely suffer a performance loss.

The less extreme case is the `remove` case. Standard `std::remove`, paired with `erase` member function (erase-remove idiom) is a great way of dealing with removing elements... unless the internal implementation makes those operations costly. On `std::list`, `std::remove` paired with naive call to `erase` will require `O(n)` (where `n` is equal to the list's `size`) operations on average. This can be drastically simplified by taking advantage of the internal implementation (in this case - pointer manipulation in the likely implementation). If you have direct access to the element you wish to remove, this operation becomes `O(1)`.

So - what's the thing about `std::find` and `std::find_if`? The thing is that there are no alternatives for `std::list` that would benefit from its internal implementation. There *could* be a member `find` and `find_if`, but they would be pretty much identical to their `<algorithm>` versions, thus there is no need to introduce them.

Answer (score 2):

The member functions in this case are more efficient and should be preferred over the more generic ones in `<algorithm>`, even though the generic functions do work on `std::list`.
The reason is `std::list` allows O(1) complexity removing and insertion of a single element anywhere, and the member functions take advantage of that.

Comment: Just to be clear, `std::list::remove` and `std::list::remove_if` are still O(n)

Comment: @luizfls What I was trying to say is that all member-function algorithms of `std::list` (even the ones you mentioned) take advantage of the fact that `std::list` allows O(1) insertion and removing. The algorithms themselves may not have O(1) complexity but that's irrelevant.